# How to show listview with optional textview?

Tags: android, xml, listview

I have XML file with layout to show fields in listview. I need flexibility this fields showed.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView
android:text="Nome da Oficina"
android:id="@+id/tvOficinaNome"/>
<TextView
android:text="Endereço da Oficina"
android:id="@+id/tvOficinaEnd"/>
<TextView
android:text="Bairro da Oficina"
android:id="@+id/tvOficinaBairro"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

In some cases, only "Nome da Oficina" must be showed. In other, only "Nome da Oficina" and "Endereço da Oficina" must be showed. In other, only "Nome da Oficina" and "Bairro da Oficina" must be showed. And in other, the three textviews.

My problem is the space between lists. How to solve?!

ps. I´m using ViewHolder extendending ArrayAdapter.

[image: Image example].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your layout should have the wrap_content for its height:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<TextView
android:text="Nome da Oficina"
android:id="@+id/tvOficinaNome"/>
<TextView
android:text="Endereço da Oficina"
android:id="@+id/tvOficinaEnd"/>
<TextView
android:text="Bairro da Oficina"
android:id="@+id/tvOficinaBairro"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Also, in your adapter, set the visibility to `View.GONE` for the textview(s) you want to hide, for example:

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    . . . 
    tvOficinaBairro.setVisibility(View.GONE)
    return convertView;
}
```